# How to represent an integer in binary

Tags: python

I'm looking for the best efficient way to represent a number in binary.

For example: 5 is represented in binary as 0101.

Of course I can calculate it "manually" and put it in a function, but is there a better way than that?

Comment: I think you mean binary representation?   "5" is the representation of  5 in decimal...

Comment: Are you asking how to print a number in binary: ie... `bin(5)`?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function like this

```
>>> format(5, "04b")
'0101'
>>> format(5, "0b")
'101'
```

You might also want to read about the [`format specifications`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: and how can I ignore redundant zeroes?

Comment: @user3045065 If you simply say `format(5, "0b")`, like shown in the answer, you ll not get the leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something here, but use [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin):

```
>>> bin(5)
'0b101'
>>> bin(5)[2:]
'101'
```